# Angularjs and Google maps marker cluster

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I'm new with Google Maps and I add [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) but I have the same problem of official plunker code [plunker](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!marker-clusterer.html), markers don't appear.
This is my Angularjs code:

```
//Google maps
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngMap', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.select']);
app.controller('mapController', ['$scope','$http', 'NgMap', function($scope, $http, NgMap)  {
    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
        //Get all buildings for maps
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/booking/building/1',
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (typeof response.data.success == 'undefined'){
                window.location.href = "/500";
            }else if (response.data.success==true){
                for (var i=0; i < response.data.result.length;i++){
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data.result[i].latitude, response.data.result[i].longitude);
                    vm.dynMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({position:latLng, title:response.data.result[i].name}));
                }
            }else if (response.data.success==false)
                notifyMessage(response.data.result, 'error');
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            window.location.href = "/500";
        });
        vm.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, vm.dynMarkers, {});
    });
});
```

In this case I have only 1 city, but in the future I may have a loto of coordinates.
In Html I have this script about ng-map:

```
<!-- Maps -->
<script th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/angular-maps/ng-map.min.js}"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
    src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/testapp/scripts/markerclusterer.js"></script>

<script>
    MarkerClusterer.prototype.MARKER_CLUSTER_IMAGE_PATH_ 
      = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png';  //changed image path 
  </script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key">
    </script>
```

I tryed to remove

```
<script>MarkerClusterer.prototype.MARKER_CLUSTER_IMAGE_PATH = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png';  //changed image path 
  </script>
```

but the result still the same. I would like to uso only maps CDN link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `vm.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, vm.dynMarkers, {});` is called before `for` inside ajax is terminated so the vatiable is empty so I moved it after the end of `for` and it works

```
for (var i=0; i < response.data.result.length;i++){
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data.result[i].latitude, response.data.result[i].longitude);
    vm.dynMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({position:latLng, title:response.data.result[i].name}));
}
vm.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, vm.dynMarkers, {});
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your app's code? It looks really cool!